# Confusion in upper type bound and lower type bound

Tags: scala

```
 */
class Parent 

class Child extends Parent

class GrandChild extends Child

object main{

  def test[B >: Child](x : B) = x; // B should be of type Child or Parent

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    test(new Parent); //works. B == Parent
    test(new Child); //works. B == Child
    test (new GrandChild) // works!!! Surprise!!! B == GrandParent. This should not work, right?

  }
}
```

I was expecting that test (new GrandChild) should give compilation error. How is it working? Am I understanding type bound wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

Since `GrandChild` extends `Child` the compiler has chosen `B` type parameter to be `Child` in the invocation

```
test(new GrandChild)
```

if you specify the type explicitly you get the error you expect:

```
test[GrandChild](new GrandChild)
```

Answer (score 0):

B >: Child means that B should be supertype of Child, all these classes are Parent (Child and GrandChild), because all extends from Parent.

Comment: If B >: Child means B should be supertype of Child, then 
test (new GrandChild)  should fail because GrandChild is not supertype of Child. It should be a compilation error

Comment: new Child and new GrandChild are instances of Parent, upcast is performed here to Parent